# Troubleshooting Oh-My-Fish configuration making fish really slow

Tags: configuration, fish

Without changing the configuration my fish shell started to be really slow, like between 1 and 5 seconds to a simple `ls` command.

Note that the slow behaviour started suddenly. I have a local install and no admin rights.

I have no `set -U var` in my config files or other “add to path” problem that could give long (path) variables to process.

I know it is not much to proceed right now but I will add more information if I can.

I managed to pinned down that Oh My Fish is responsible by renaming `~/.config/fish/conf.d/omf.fish`, but my `~/.local/share/omf` directory contains so much that I need some leads to troubleshoot. I have the bobthefish theme.

The command `omf doctor` gives

```
Oh My Fish version:   7
OS type:              Linux
Fish version:         fish, version 3.1.0
Git version:          git version 2.25.1
Git core.autocrlf:    no
Checking for a sane environment...
Your shell is ready to swim.
```

**Update:** without changing anything everything went back to normal. I suspect a command in the prompt was temporarilly taking a long time and that the server was at fault, not Oh-My-Fish.

Comment: If you start fish with the `fish_trace` environment variable set to 1, it will print commands as they are run, so you can figure out which commands are slow.

Comment: Run `top -c` whenever a machine is slow for non-obvious reasons.  `iotop` is also important (but needs root privs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out fish was not at fault, even if I don't know what was. I'm gessing a call in the prompt that is not on the vanilla prompt. I'll accept this answer after a while in case anyone has a better idea of what might have happened.